# Volume element of symmetric definite matrices in polar coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra

I have a difficulty to understand the following statement. I don't ask for a proof but just understand the statement concretely (what it does mean, how to apply it...)

Let $\mathcal P_n$ be the space of symmetric definite matrices of order $n$. Equipped with $g_p(X,Y)=tr(P^{-1}XP^{-1}Y)$, $\mathcal P_n$ becomes a Riemannian manifold. The volum element on it is 
$$dv(Y)=det(Y)^{-(n+1)/2} \prod_{i\le j} dY_{ij}.$$
We write each $Y\in\mathcal P_n$ as $Y=U^{t} \text{diag}(e^r)U$ with $U\in O_n$ and $r=(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$ such that $r_1\le\cdots \le r_n$. From here I am lost. In polar coordinates, the volume element takes the following form 
$$dv(Y)=8^{n(n-1)/4} det(\theta) \prod_{i<j} \sinh(\frac{r_i-r_j}{2}) \prod dr_j$$
where $\theta_{ij}=\sum_k U_{jk} dU_{ik}$ and the notation $\det(\theta)$ is used for the exterior product $\det(\theta)=\wedge_{i<j} \theta_{ij}.$

I did not understand the définitions of $\theta_{ij}$ and $U_{ij}$.